# Top part of website is hidden when in a small browser window

Tags: html, css, hide, margin, center

Since a couple of weeks i'm building a new website. This website starts to look pretty good but there is one problem.

When i view my website in a browser window that is smaller than the actual webpage, the menubar on top of the page gets cut off. I can't scroll up and down the page, but the top part can't be reeched.

This problem probably has something to do with the 'center' code I use for center vertically. Is there an solution where i can keep my webpaged centered but still can reached the hole page once I'm using a small window?

I all ready solved the problem in Chrome mobile by using a 'viewport' metatag.
Sadly the desktop browsers like IE, safari, Chrome etc. still refuse to show the topbar of my webpage when the window is small.

Here is a link to my website:
[test.themissingsticks.com](http://test.themissingsticks.com)

Try viewing it in a fullscrene window (with a resolution above 800px height) and view it with a window of less than 600px height. You will notice the gray menubar on the top of my website will not show, net even when you try to scroll upwards.

The website is centered by the following line of css:

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -340px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -513px;
```

width of the page is 1026px and height is 680px.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add the code you have used to vertically center the site

Comment: The way you have positioned all of the elements on your page using absolute positioning and negative margins is just a bit crazy. There are much simpler ways to do this. I'd advise going back to basics and doing some research into best practice with regards to centering a website and building websites in general.

Comment: Hi! To many html/css discrepancies. You should refactor you code completely using relative positioning on most elements.

Comment: You're using percentages in your alignment, combined with negative margins. While this works great for modal windows, it is *not* recommended to align your website. If I were you, I'd concentrate on using the scaffolding of a system like grid960 (http://960.gs/) or Twitter Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).

Comment: I'm going to try an other method of centering my page vertically. I found a overview of differnt methods here: 
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/ 

Now I'm bothered by the coins of "Method 2". I'm gonna try method 3 and I will let you know if it's any better.

Answer (score 2):

go to style.csss
change css of "menutms"
replace **margin-top: -340px;** by **margin-top: -300px;**
it will work in all browser.

Comment: @user1677453 try it and tell me what happen.

Comment: The problem is still there, only the menu bar is lowered.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! I made 2 div's for vertical and horizontal center alignment. These two are positioned absolutely. the rest of the hole webpage is positioned relatively inside these div's.

The only downside is that IE9 is not displaying the site very well.

Here's a disciption of the method:
http://www.search-this.com/2008/05/15/easy-vertical-centering-with-css/